# How to make incomplete array/struct initialization an error or warning?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-flags

If we define an array/struct like this:

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, };
struct b { int c; int d; } e = { 1, };
```

or even:

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3 };
struct b { int c; int d; } e = { 1 };
```

we get no error from C compiler as the missing elements are initialized with a 0 default, like when we write explicitly:

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 0 };
struct b { int c; int d; } e = { 1, 0 };
```

Is there a way to disable the default initialization of an array in C, so that the compiler gives an error or warning when the elements are not all defined?

I am using gcc 4.8.0 (MinGW).

Comment: For the field initializers, you can use `-Wmissing-field-initializers` warning, and you can turn it into an error using `-Werror`.

Comment: @BillyJoe I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to force the remaining elements to be indeterminate instead of initialized to zero.

Comment: @JorgeBellon That's the answer. You should put it in a proper answer.

Comment: And unfortunately there's no equivalent for arrays, so `struct {int a,b;} struc_array[5] = { {5,0} };` will not result in errors despite the missing initializers for indices 1..4 of the array of structs.  That is, the structs at indices 1..4 will be default-initialized, even with `-Wmissing-field-initializers`.

Comment: OK, I started asking about arrays, but I was actually interested in structs, so the `-Wmissing-field-initializers` actually satisfy my needs and answers half of the question. We can answer the other half saying that there is no equivalent then.

Comment: @JorgeBellon While this is excellent for structs, it won´t work for arrays: https://godbolt.org/z/nUm24o

Comment: @klutt I modified again the question title because like this it is more complete and corresponds to what actually I am looking for.

Comment: @JorgeBellon If you want to make an answer with your comment, supposing as other have said that there is no equivalent for arrays, otherwise I will answer it myself.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because it didn't answer the whole question, but now it seems this has been already asked before. Maybe close as duplicate.

Comment: What about `int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, };` with `static_assert(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) == 5)`? It will not detect `int a[] = { [4] = 1, };` but still.

Comment: @Mike Kinghan yes, I think that answeres my question. I searched before but I didn't find it.